# Custom Navbar titleView size issue when pushing next ViewController

Tags: ios, size, uinavigationbar, titleview

I'm trying to have a custom titleView for Iphone app iOS 5.0+ . So I placed a graphic like this :

```
UIView *customTitleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 104, 72)]; 

UIImageView *customTitleGraphics = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]; 
[customTitleGraphics setTag:kNavigationImageView]; 
CGRect myFrame = customTitleGraphics.frame; 
myFrame.origin.y = 15.0; 
myFrame.origin.x = -3.0; 

customTitleGraphics.frame = myFrame; 

[customTitleView addSubview:customTitleGraphics]; 
navigationItem.titleView = customTitleView;
```

And It works so far. The problem i Have is when I try to push another viewController: It looks like the titleView get cut off suddenly when the animation starts.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ysiroxayfld1l3/titleview.mov?v=1mci

Do you have any idea where I'm wrong?

Comment: Are you refereeing to the lower part of the image?
Or the fact the image is fade out and then fade in again...

Comment: the lower part yes.. the fading I added to hide that issue =)

Comment: I guess it clips the views when doing the animation. Are you sure the UIImageView/customTitleView is not out of bounds?

Comment: what you mean for out of bounds? which bounds?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the title view is resized by the `UINavigationBar` when you push the new VC to the navigation stack. What I would suggest would be to prevent the navigation view from clipping to bounds…